# How to properly edit the legend using the ax function in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, label

I have the following code, it outputs a persistence diagram for random points on the plane. Everything is almost exactly how I want it, my last issue is that I would love to have a horizontal red line in the legend to the left of "current radius = #" for my graph on the right (this is ax2 in the code), I am also getting the following error message every time the ax2.legend(loc = 'lower right', title = f'current radius = {i}') line runs.

"No artists with labels found to put in legend.  Note that artists whose label start with an underscore are ignored when legend() is called with no argument.'

Anyone know how I might be able to fix this issue?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
from celluloid import Camera
import numpy as np

# center of the original circle
h = 0       # x-coord of center
k = 0       # y-coord of center

# a randomly determined selection of angles
theta = np.array( [1 * np.pi / 6, 2 * np.pi / 3, 4 * np.pi / 5, 
                   1 * np.pi / 5, 2 * np.pi / 5, 4 * np.pi / 7,
                   1 * np.pi / 4, 2 * np.pi / 9, 4 * np.pi / 3,
                   1 * np.pi / 3, 3 * np.pi / 2, 5 * np.pi / 9, 
                   1 * np.pi / 2, 3 * np.pi / 8, 5 * np.pi / 4,
                   1 * np.pi / 1, 3 * np.pi / 7, 5 * np.pi / 3,
                   11 * np.pi / 6, 11 * np.pi / 10, 7 * np.pi / 6,
                   11 * np.pi / 7,  7 * np.pi /  4, 1 * np.pi / 10] )


# calculating coordinates
r = np.linspace(.1,2,24)        # the vector of radii that will spread the original points out
x = h + r * np.cos(theta)
y = k + r * np.sin(theta)

# diagram set up
radii = np.linspace(0,1,50)                                  # non truncated list of radii
trunc_radii = np.around(radii, 3)                            # truncated list of radii
death_list = np.array( [.041, .061, .102, .122, .143,        # list of radii that cause deaths
                        .163, .184, .224, .245, .286,
                        .306, .327, .408, .429, .694] )

plotted_deaths = []                                          # plotted deaths so far

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)
camera = Camera(fig)

for i in trunc_radii :
    ax1.scatter(x, y, color = 'green', marker = 'o', s = 15)

    for xx,yy in zip(x,y) :
        cir = mpatches.Circle((xx, yy), i, color = 'r',fill = True, zorder = 0)
        ax1.add_patch(cir)

    ax1.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='datalim')
    ax1.set_title('Random Points in the Plane')
    ax1.set(xlabel='x-axis', ylabel='y-axis')
    ax1.set_xlim([-2.25, 2.25])
    ax1.set_ylim([-2.25, 2.25])

    a = np.arange(0,1.1,.1)
    b = a
    ax2.plot(a,b, color = 'b')
    ax2.axhline(y = i, color = 'r', linestyle = '-')

    if i in death_list :
        plotted_deaths.append(i)

    for j in plotted_deaths :
        ax2.plot(0, j, marker = "o", markersize = 5, markeredgecolor = "green", markerfacecolor = "green")

    ax2.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='datalim')
    ax2.set_title('0-Dimensional Persistence Diagram')
    ax2.set(xlabel='Birth', ylabel='Death')
    ax2.legend(loc = 'lower right', title = f'current radius = {i}')

    fig.set_figheight(6)
    fig.set_figwidth(12)

    camera.snap()

animation = camera.animate()
# animation.save('0-D persistence diagram for random points on the plane.gif')
plt.show()
```

And here is a picture of the output:
[image]

Comment: `ax2.axhline(y = i, color = 'r', linestyle = '-', label=f'current radius = {i}')` doesn't work?

Comment: It does add the line I want but it prints with every iteration of the loop so that just stacks the label repeatedly, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases it can make sense to add the legend manually.
This way you get full control of what the legend will show!

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f, ax = plt.subplots()

# just remember the last plotted line of the loop
for i in range(10):
    l, = ax.plot([i]*2, c="g", lw=2)
    l2, = ax.plot([-i]*2, c="r", lw=2)

# you can also always add a custom artist to the legend!
custom_legend_line = plt.Line2D([], [], c="b", ls="--")

# create a custom legend
handles = [l, l2, custom_legend_line]
labels = ["first line", "second line", "custom_legend_line"]

ax.legend(handles, labels, loc="upper center")
```

[image]